# Like/Unlike Button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to create a Like/Unlike button with jQuery! Here's what I did,

Here's the HTML,

```
<span class="like-button">{% if request.user in likes.all %}Unlike{% else %}Like{% endif %}</span>
```

Here's the jQuery,

```
$('.like-button').click(function(){
    var x = $(this);
    x.toggleClass('like-button');
    if(x.hasClass('like-button')){
    x.text('Like');
    } else {
    x.text('Unlike');
    }
});
```

When I press `Like` button it works fine & text changes into `Unlike`, but problem is after refreshing the webpage when I press `Unlike` button it takes 2 clicks to turn back into `Like`. How can we solve it or is there any other better way to do this?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the class to be conditional too

```
<span {% if request.user in likes.all %}class="like-button"{% endif %}>{% if request.user in likes.all %}Unlike{% else %}Like{% endif %}</span>
```

Comment: There's a problem with this solution. If the "like-button" class is not present on the element, the "click" event won't get triggered. So it will never go back to "like" or "unlike".

Comment: Make it one class responsible for the click ie "like-button" and one for the liked button ie "liked-button"

Comment: your last comment would work, but it's not the answer you posted.

Comment: @lapinozz Sir, I'm still facing the same problem. Can you please paste the complete working answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second time you load the page, the button also has the `like-button` class on the element. So when you click, it removes it (no matter what the text is) and changes the text to "unlike" (again). That's why you need a different identifier.

I suggest you add a second class to your element or an id to get the element.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yemjsme/2/) (in this example, I display two buttons to show you one on first load and one on the refresh page (which doesn't have the class)).

For example:

HTML

```
<span id="btn-like" class="like">{% if request.user in likes.all %}Unlike{% else %}Like{% endif %}</span>
```

HTML on the refresh (notice how there isn't a like class)

```
<span id="btn-like">{% if request.user in likes.all %}Unlike{% else %}Like{% endif %}</span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#btn-like').click(function(){
    var x = $(this);
    x.toggleClass('like');
    if(x.hasClass('like')){
        x.text('Like');
    } else {
        x.text('Unlike');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sir, still facing the same problem. It's working fine when I press `Like` button, the text changes into `Unlike` & so on, but after refreshing the webpage when I press Unlike button its still taking 2 clicks to change back into `Like`.

Comment: @KumarShivam As I've mentioned in my answer, the reason your code is not working on the refresh is because your element has the class "like-button" even though it's in an "unlike" state. That's why you need to click twice.

Comment: Sir, I tried the code you've given but still facing the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Id` to that button and bind click event on that id and also check for the class `.like-button` if text is already `Unlink`

jQuery

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  var x = $(this);
  x.toggleClass('like-button');
  if (x.hasClass('like-button')) {
    x.text('Like');
  } else {
    x.text('Unlike');
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<span {% if request.user in likes.all %}class="like-button" {% endif %} id="button">{% if request.user in likes.all %}Unlike{% else %}Like{% endif %}</span>
```